# Decoration of problem sets

Tags: text-decorations

Did anyone have an experience with formatting the problem set for home assignments?

I'm looking for results like in attached picture:

[image]

I found the similar result for a "caption" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books
But I have no idea how to make that "table-styled" representation that includes Given / Find / SI units / Solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What does 'Given / Find / SI units / Solution' mean?

Comment: @cfr : I'm talking about that table-styles graphical representation of problem

Comment: As far I see the output could be  done with a very simple  table. You must provide a MWE and be more specific about where you get stuck.